# Date formatting - For Each loop changing outputs

Tags: excel, vba

The age old date conundrum in Excel. I am looking for advice/ help on the below please!

I have a set of dates:

[image]

Important to note about these dates: They are output from an array using `start_date = Format$("01-" & sheet_date, "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")` and `end_date = Format$(DateSerial(Year(DateValue(sheet_date)), Month(DateValue(sheet_date)) + 1, 0), "\ dd\/mm\/yyyy\")` respectively.

The reason for this is to hold UK format. If I use any other way the `Vendor Start Dates` default to US.

Now with the output dates (as above) I am trying to run through the range of dates, and "trim" the space while holding the same format. I say "trim" because the simple method does not yield the desired UK format, and the dates format to US.

Now for the interesting part. I have tried a couple of simple things in testing how to maintain the UK format and have come up with the below (testing on one cell):

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim start_date As Date

    start_date = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Value = start_date

End Sub
```

This maintains the date format correctly, as seen below:

[image]

Now, when I run this in a `For Each` loop it **does not** maintain the UK format for some reason. I use the following code:

```vb
Sub explicit_date_clean()

    Dim date_range As Range, cell As Range
    Dim temp_date As Date


    With ActiveSheet
        'set range
        Set date_range = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="**Vendor Start Date", LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 2)

        For Each cell In date_range
            temp_date = cell.Value
            cell.Value = temp_date
        Next cell

    End With

End Sub
```

This is now the output running it through the `For Each` loop:

[image]

Any ideas on this SO?

Comment: You should avoid the problem entirely by using actual date values at the start, not Strings resulting from `Format$`

Comment: Instead of working with strings, adjust the numberformat of the cell to display the DMY format. Otherwise you will continue to have problems.

Comment: @Rory if I output date value they format straight to US dates and do not hold UK format - hence why I have taken that step

Comment: @RonRosenfeld a new workbook is generated each time the process is run, otherwise that would be an option.

Comment: How is the workbook generated?

Comment: Have a look at `DateValue`. You can then use the date format instead of a string

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I set a `Workbook` object with `Workbooks.Add`

Comment: @Zac `DateValue` doesn't seem to work - on the output the dates format to US

Comment: Use `DateValue` with `Format` (i.e. `Format(DateValue(MyDate)), "dd/mm/yyyy")`)

Comment: Just add the cell formatting code to the macro in which you have the  `Workbooks.Add` line

Comment: And how do the dates actually get into that new workbook? If they are real dates formatting should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

To generate a list of dates which will display in UK format, instead of using the `Format` function, just generate **real** dates and format the cell to show the format you want.

In your question, you suggest these dates are based on `sheet_date` but you don't mention where that comes from, so I hard-coded it in the macro, but you can change that.

Just note that the displayed results are real dates in DMY format.

```
Option Explicit
Sub dtS()
    Dim date_range As Range
    Dim temp_date As Date
    Dim vDates(0 To 10, 1 To 2) 'array to hold the dates
    Dim I As Long

    Dim WB As Workbook, WS As Worksheet

    'not sure how you are defining `sheet_date` or the number of rows
    'you'll need to edit this for that.

    'Note that the date below is interpreted as MDY
    Const sheet_date As Date = #2/1/2020# 'eg 1 Feb 2020

Set WB = ThisWorkbook 'but in your case, it would be the added workbook
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("sheet1") 'or whatever the relevant sheet is.

'where we will put the dates
With WS
    Set date_range = .Range(.Cells(1, "BI"), .Cells(10, "BJ"))
End With

'write **real** dates into the array
vDates(0, 1) = "**Vendor Start Date"
vDates(0, 2) = "**Vendor End Date"

For I = 1 To UBound(vDates)
    vDates(I, 1) = DateSerial(Year(sheet_date), Month(sheet_date), 1)
    vDates(I, 2) = DateAdd("m", 1, vDates(I, 1)) - 1
Next I

'Format the results cell and write the results there
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With date_range
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
    .Value = vDates
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]